# How to do joins in Xpath 1.0?

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-1.0

I wonder how to do joins in XPath 1.0.

I have an XML file looking like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <author>
       <id>MM</id>
       <gender>M</gender>
       <name>Max Mustermann</name>
   </author>
   <author>
       <id>JD</id>
       <gender>F</gender>
       <name>Joanne Doe</name>
   </author>
   <book>
      <author_id>MM</author_id>
      <title>Wie werde ich reich?</title>
      <isbn>123456</isbn>
   </book>
   <book>
      <author_id>JD</author_id>
      <title>Boring jokes</title>
      <isbn>4353442</isbn>
   </book>
</root>
```

My goal is to write an XPath 1.0 query to get all books titles together with the author gender. I know how to select books and author genders, but how to combine this? How to do the join?
In SQL, I would write

```
SELECT book.title, author.gender FROM author, book WHERE book.author_id = author.id;
```

Comment: I don't think there is any provision to do that yet. However, to achieve this, you may create two different lists of web elements and map the contents of each of them by iterating and saving it in desired collection object.

Comment: XML is generated by a third party software and I need the XPath queries for report generation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a grouping problem. Since you said in a comment `I have only the possibilities of XSLT 1.0` you can use [`xsl:key`/`key()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#key) to perform a lookup.

Here's an example. I create a key of all `author` elements based on the `id` element.

That will allow me to access the `author` from `book` by using the `author_id` element.

**XML Input**

```
<root>
    <author>
        <id>MM</id>
        <gender>M</gender>
        <name>Max Mustermann</name>
    </author>
    <author>
        <id>JD</id>
        <gender>F</gender>
        <name>Joanne Doe</name>
    </author>
    <book>
        <author_id>MM</author_id>
        <title>Wie werde ich reich?</title>
        <isbn>123456</isbn>
    </book>
    <book>
        <author_id>JD</author_id>
        <title>Boring jokes</title>
        <isbn>4353442</isbn>
    </book>
</root>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="authors" match="author" use="id"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="book"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="book">
    <xsl:if test="not(position()=1)">
      <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('TITLE: ',title,
      ' GENDER: ',key('authors',author_id)/gender)"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
TITLE: Wie werde ich reich? GENDER: M
TITLE: Boring jokes GENDER: F
```

Fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6r5Gh48

Comment: This is not Muenchian grouping. Just a simple lookup.

Comment: @michael.hor257k - You're right. Not sure why I had muenchian grouping in mind when there's no grouping at all. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is sufficient for what you need, but this xpath expression:

```
*//*[self::gender or self::title]
```

will select

```
M
F
Wie werde ich reich?
Boring jokes
```

EDIT: The expressions

```
(//*[self::gender])[1]
```

and

```
(//*[self::title])[1]
```

will select the first gender and title, respectively.

The fundamental problem with the xml is its structure: except for the ordering, there is no indication that the first author is necessarily the author of the first book. It's also entirely possible that one author would write more than one book or the one book will be written by more than one author. To make a necessary connection between a specific author and a specific book, a different structure would have to be used.

Comment: Does this provide the association? I need "title + gender" together and not just a list with all gender and titles in the file.

Comment: @user3992979 - for that you may have to use some processor (xquery? lxml in python?), I believe - see edit.

Comment: I have only the possibilities of XSLT 1.0. The linking of the books and authors here happens with the ID: book/author_id matches author/id. This creates the association between books and authors.

Comment: @user3992979 - I added a XSLT 1.0 option. If you can really use XSLT, you should update your question to include those tags.